# Mode to create a file when it doesnt exist

Tags: python

I am trying to write to a CSV file using the below line,I thougt "ab+" will create the file even though its not present but apparently its failing..any idea which mode should I open to create the file when it doesnt exist?

```
#Keep appending date and count everytime this script is run
c = csv.writer(open("//location/scripts/" + csv_file + ".csv", "ab+"))
```

Error:-

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//location/scripts/BT_FM_BUGGY_FIX_CRTREND.csv'
```

Comment: Why are there two slashes at the start of the path?

Answer (score 1):

`a+` **does** create the file if it is not present:

```
>>> import os
>>> from tempfile import mkdtemp
>>> dir = mkdtemp()
>>> os.listdir(dir)
[]
>>> open(os.path.join(dir, 'test.txt'), 'ab+').write('test')
>>> os.listdir(dir)
['test.txt']
```

However, the mode does not create *directories*. The directory you wanted to create the file in is not present. Create that first, or correct the directory if it is supposed to exist already.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters - directory exists

Comment: @user2639990: What does `os.listdir()` tell you is there?